# Aren't answers to questions dependent clauses? How do you punctuate one after the question?

Tags: questions, jokes, dependent-clause

For example, which one(s) is correct:

1. Why did the chicken cross the road?  To get to the other side.
2. Why did the chicken cross the road:  to get to the other side.
3. Why did the chicken cross the road?--To get to the other side.

Please put any other ways to construct this sequence.

Comment: Only the first one is correct. Why would an answer necessarily be a dependent clause?

Comment: I saw some answers as incomplete sentences in terms of Subject and Verb requirements.  Some of them only have subjects:  i.e. "What is a chicken?  A bird."  "A bird." is just a subject.

Answer (score 3):

> Why did the chicken cross the road? ... To get to the other side.

or

> "Why did the chicken cross the road?"
>
> "To get to the other side."

(answered by a second person)

doesn't contain two sentences as strictly defined. However, the 'rule' 'you must never use / write / ... other than in true sentences' is a pseudo-rule. We don't worry about saying 'Yes', 'Why?', 'In the pantry', ''Hello'. These are often called 'sentence substitutes', or 'sentence fragments' where they're obvious ellipted sentences ('[The mustard is] in the pantry'). They're quite acceptable in the correct place, and are punctuated as if they were true sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, question and answer are **two sentences** in their own right.

Occasionally, one may construct a sentence where one answers a question within. In that case, yes, the answer is a clause, and is *separated by a comma*.

> Why did the chicken cross the road, to get to the other side.

This is an awkward construction making the *Why did* redundant. However, it has the advantage of presenting a complete argument in an integrated sentence.

> The first thing … is to get rid of the business owners'/leaders' ego. Why am I saying this, because there are people out there who can do it better than you … ([Building a Team](http://www.projectconnect.com.au/Documents/Wedge/Building_A_Team_To_Build_Your_Business.pdf))

Comment: I have redressed the phantom downvote. Though I'd avoid the awkward construction myself.

Comment: This looks so bad I don't think it can possibly be correct. Can you find a reference saying this is acceptable?